# Kivy: Index of the child Button that was pressed

Tags: python, kivy

In this very simple code here, how do I find which Button is pressed? In particular I want the index of the pressed Button, not the name nor the text of that Button.

Python:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class AddItems(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddItems, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range (5):
            b = Button(text = str(i+1), size_hint= (1, None))
            self.add_widget(b)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    pass


MainApp().run()
```

KV:

```
Scroll:
<Scroll@ScrollView>:
    AddItems:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
<AddItems>:
    cols: 1
    spacing: 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `index` as an attribute of the `Button`:

```
class AddItems(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddItems, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(5):
            b = Button(text=str(i+1), size_hint=(1, None), on_release=self.released)
            b.index = i
            self.add_widget(b)

    def released(self, button):
        print('released:', button.text, button.index)
```

Comment: That very easy answer really surprised  me, like wow is that so simple? But what if that Button opens a new Screen and in that new Screen I have a Delete Button and I can delete just that certain button.index. Or I can add a new random function on that certain button.index. How can I use index in another class?